# Using Wordpress as a Mobile App Backend

Tags: mobile

I'm searching for a fast way to develop a backend for Mobile Apps.
The idea is to use Wordpress as a backend.

My problem is: How can i serve the information to the Mobile App?
I saw the JSon plugin but you can't use it for custom post types.

I was thinking at xml, is there a plugin i can use or should i code specific pages that serves xml?

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain your problem better. I have no idea why you need _serve information_ to something if you are already using the back-end which is made to do that: serve information.

Comment: I need to develop a Mobile App based on PhoneGap and i was wondering what is the fastest way to create a complete and easy to use backend. Since Wordpress already comes with all the stuff needed (custom posts, authentications,media upload), i'd like to find a way to provide the informations to the PhoneGap App. I know a mobile version of the site will be better but sometimes there isn't a website to start from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use WP and all it's associated goodness for a mobile app backend (I'm going to do it soon myself).

Custom post types are not a problem. Make a page, grab the data with a WP_Query and serve up the query results as JSON instead of HTML, though you'll have to do this bit yourself I'd wager (I'm planning on doing it).

That's only one part of it of course, if you can give a bit more information about the project you might get some more insightful answers!

Comment: After some tests i ended up with the same idea!